# Java language - show number 1-100

Tags: java, text, numbers

It concerns Java language.
How to display numbers 1-100 and those that are divisible by 3 and 5 display as any word ex. test? Please help me and thank you for your time.

```
public class zad1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Zadanie nr 1");
    int zmienna = 15;
    if (zmienna % 3 == 0)
        System.out.println("Fizz");
    else
        System.out.println("int");
    if (zmienna % 5 == 0)
        System.out.println("Bizz");
    else
        System.out.println("int");
    if (zmienna % 5 == 0 && zmienna % 3 == 0)
        System.out.println("FizzBizz");
    else
        System.out.println("int");
}
}
```

Comment: By writing some code?

Comment: Most simple code

Comment: I need to display these numbers only in the console.

Comment: It’s unclear. Do you mean you want your output to be 1 2 Fizz 4 Bizz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Bizz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBizz 16 etc.?

Comment: I think you should find a better variable name (according to Google Translate zmienna means variable; what’s Polish for number?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic to print is fine, all you need to do is to wrap the code into a `for` loop and excute it from 1 to 100, e.g.:

```
for(int zmienna = 0 ; zmienna <= 100 ; zmienna++){
    if (zmienna % 5 == 0 && zmienna % 3 == 0)
        System.out.println("FizzBizz");
    else if (zmienna % 3 == 0)
        System.out.println("Fizz");
    else if (zmienna % 5 == 0)
        System.out.println("Bizz");
    else
        System.out.println("int");
}
```